# Custom setter for tuple property (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, swift

I have a computed property in my class that is an optional tuple:

```
var contents: (Int, Bool)?
```

I want to write a custom setter but don't know how to reference the tuple components individually. Anyone knows? I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
var contents: (Int colorNumber, Bool selected)? {
    // getter & setter here...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use let to decompose a tuple

```
var iVal:Int?
var bVal:Bool?

var contents:(Int, Bool)? {
    get {
        if iVal != nil && bVal != nil {
            return (iVal!, bVal!)
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    set {
        if newValue != nil {
            let (i, b) = newValue!    // decompose the tuple
            iVal = i
            bVal = b
        }
        else {
            iVal = nil
            bVal = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to explicitly implement `set` and `get`. In the setter you can access the new value using the `newValue` implicit parameter.

Suppose your tuple is backed by individual data members, then you would implement the property as follows:

```
var colorNumber: Int?
var selected: Bool?

var contents: (Int, Bool)? {
    get {
        if self.colorNumber != nil && self.selected != nil {
            return (self.colorNumber!, self.selected!)
        }
        return nil
    }
    set {
        if let value = newValue {
            colorNumber = value.0
            selected = value.1
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use named parameters:

```
var colorNumber: Int?
var selected: Bool?

var contents: (colorNumber: Int, selected: Bool)? {
    get {
        if self.colorNumber != nil && self.selected != nil {
            return (self.colorNumber!, self.selected!)
        }
        return nil
    }
    set {
        if let value = newValue {
            colorNumber = value.colorNumber
            selected = value.selected
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like these are called "Unnamed Tuples" and "Named Tuples" (as seen here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/75289/swift-tutorial-part-3-tuples-protocols-delegates-table-views) but Apple just calls them... um, not much at all. Anyway, this is great, and the decomposition answer (above) is great too.